# Create a vector of multiple series from two vectors

Tags: r

I'm sure there is a super-simple solution to this, I just can't figure out what it is.

I have a long, single-variable dataset in R. I can identify the beginning and end of the multiple relevant ranges throughout, I just need to filter out the rest.

So given a vector x:

```
> x <- c(2400:2600)
```

And vectors of start points and end points:

```
> startpoints <- c(1,11,101)
> endpoints <- c(3,13,103)
```

I need to return the subset of x that looks like this:

```
> x[c(1:3, 11:13, 101:103)]
[1] 2400 2401 2402 2410 2411 2412 2500 2501 2502
```

I've tried this:

```
> x[startpoints:endpoints]
```

But R just takes the first value from each vector and returns that series:

```
[1] 2400 2401 2402
```

...with a couple of warnings

My startpoints and endpoints vectors should always be equal in length, although they may vary together in length with different datasets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `mapply` to get the sequence between corresponding elements of 'startpoints', 'endpoints' and this can subset the 'x' vector.

```
x[mapply(`:`, startpoints, endpoints)]
#[1] 2400 2401 2402 2410 2411 2412 2500 2501 2502
```

If the sequence are of different lengths, as @nicola mentioned, `mapply` returns a `list`, so we need to `unlist` it

```
x[unlist(mapply(`:`, startpoints, endpoints))]
```

Comment: Much better `unlist(Map(":", startpoints, endpoints))`: if the difference is not fixed between `endpoints` and `startpoints` as it is in the example, your line won't work. Try for instance with `endpoints<-c(3,13,104)`.